# In Delphi how many Data Modules (DM) I most have in a project?

Tags: delphi

I'm looking for an advice.

In Delphi how many Data Modules (DM) i should have in a project with a lot of apps (forms) for best practices?

Comment: You can have as many as you need. Delphi's frameworks don't care.  In practice, you probably don't need more than a handful at most.

Comment: Thanks for your advices

Comment: More than one or zero. A project with a single datamodule is a common Delphi antipattern. That single datamodule quickly becomes a brittle code monster, full of bugs and difficult to change. If you're doing a TDataset style application, keep only closely related components on the one datamodule. If find you have more than 6-8 datasets on a datamodule, maybe split it into two datamodules. Start with that as your rule of thumb and you'll soon work out what is best suited to your application.

Comment: As many as you feel you need. We can't advise you on how many that would be. You're the only one who can decide that, based on your own code and needs.

Comment: Usually you'll want to separate your business logic into the datamodules and your form logic into frames/forms. With a growing->large application you might get stuck with too many/overcomplicated designtime links between forms and dm's. I tend to make the datamodule owner of the form, some times other way around and link up datasources etc during runtime using the `Loaded` method override and cast the `Owner` as required during the link phase.